# Remove avatar - carrierwave and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, carrierwave

I'm having an unbelievable amount of trouble getting the Carrierwave `:remove_avatar` checkbox to work in my Devise profile edit form. I've been following the carrierwave documentation and [wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-use-carrierwave-with-devise#4-add-avatar-display-and-upload-to-the-edit-form-optional).

I've mounted the uploader to the User model. I've added `:avatar` and `:remove_avatar` to in the ApplicationController sanitizer

**application_controller.rb**

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
        u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, 
        :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :remove_avatar) 
  end
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, 
        :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

I've added the `:remove_avatar` to the edit form

**/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
   <%= image_tag(resource.avatar_url(:thumb)) %>
   <%= f.file_field :avatar, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/png' %>
   <label>
     <%= f.check_box :remove_avatar %>
     Remove avatar
   </label>

   <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>

   <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

   <%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email %>

   <div><%= link_to 'Cancel', resource %> <%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I'm not having any other problems with carrierwave except for removing the avatars. When I check the box and submit the form the picture is not removed.

I did a test where I used the users controller instead of devise's registrations controller and submitted the form to `@user` instead of `resource` and I was able to get it working. I'd rather stick to convention and use the registrations controller. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.remove_avatar!
@user.remove_avatar = true
@user.save
@user.reload
```

Try this, May help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your model:

```
  after_commit :remove_avatar!, on: :destroy
```